# Trying to find a String element inside an Array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, search

I am trying to write a method that takes a String, converts it into an Array of Strings, and then searches for a specific String within that Array.  Here is my code:

```
public static void ThereOrNaw ( String s, String s2 ){ 

    String[] words = s.split("\\s");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if( s2 == words[i] ) {
            System.out.println("Found");
        }
        else if( s2 != words[i] && (i + 1) == words.length) {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run this method it always returns "Not Found" even if the element is in the Array.  Unless, the Array of Strings has ONLY the element I am looking for.  Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Your code (and algorithm) seem over-complicated, how is your implementation supposed to differ from `System.out.println(s.contains(s2) ? "Found" : "Not Found");`?

Comment: Elliot Frisch is correct. To add more, for case sensitive approach, `s.toLowerCase().contains(s2.toLowerCase()) ? "Found" : "Not Found"`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `equals()` not `==`.

`==` compare your `String` objects not by content, but by real address in memory(in simple words).
So if you will use `equals()` you will compare `String` objects by content.
Also you can use `equalsIgnoreCase()` method if you do not care about case.

And another one little advice, check that `s2` not `null` before you will invoke `equals()`, because you don't know, which object client will send to this method.

For example:

```
if (s2 != null && s2.equals(words[i])) { ...

else if (s2 != null && !s2.equals(words[i]) ...
```

Comment: Appears to work thanks!! I'm just curious for further in depth understanding since I'm very new to Java.  Why does `equals` work but `==` does not?

Comment: @DanielUtvich I supplemented my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well as he said you don't have to use == comparing words, == compare objects

Look i made the change in your code for you:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    thereOrNaw("hola","hola");
    thereOrNaw("hola","mundo");
}

public static void thereOrNaw ( String s, String s2 ){ 

    String[] words = s.split("\\s");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if( s2.equals(words[i]) ) {
            System.out.println("Found");
        }
        else if( s2 != words[i] && (i + 1) == words.length) {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

And it gaves me:

Found
Not Found